# how can i add child node to the parents nodes in php?

Tags: php

I am reading a rootpath and  listing all the folder. I have to add some child node to every  folder programatically ?

```
<?php 
$rootpath = 'D:/Storage/';  
if ($handle = opendir($rootpath)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<li><a href=/hi.php?dev=$entry&action=viewcam>$entry</a>";
        }
  } 
closedir($handle);
?>
```

I am getting like

```
- folder1
- folder2
```

but I want like

```
- folder1
     Appple
     orange
- folder2
     Appple
     orange
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: This doesn't throw any errors? Because your first `if` and `while` loop are not closed (`}`).

Comment: Do you want to create those "nodes" in your html output only or inside the file system as files?

Comment: i want to show html output

Comment: Then just output it! No need to "create nodes". Just output the html. As easy as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to specifically "create a node" on the server side for this. All you have to do is output the html markup you want to have:

```
<?php 

$rootpath = 'D:/Storage/';  
if ($handle = opendir($rootpath)) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<li><a href=\"/hi.php?dev=$entry&action=viewcam\">$entry</a></li>\n";
            echo "<ul>\n";
            foreach (['Apple', 'orange'] as $fruit) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"\">".$fruit."</a></li>\n";
            }
            echo "</ul>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
} 
closedir($handle);
?>
```

*(I fixed a few minor issues with your code on-the-fly...)*

Obviously this is just an example to show the basic approach.

Comment: i am getting, but my approach it has to act as child node .